# Are server changes always reported in log file?

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, log-files

Is it even remotely possible that changes may be taking place on my shared hosting but are somehow not being reported in the server access log files? I have a CMS running that only I have legitimate access to and I've noticed various setting changes that I simply haven't made over the past few days. In the access logs, these changes are not reported at all, it doesn't seem as though I or anyone else has made them.

I just need to know if this is at all a possibility or if there is just no way this could happen, in which case I'll go back and investigate further.

Comment: On shared hosting? What a nightmare! If they haven't got security just perfect, then anybody could just use [drush](http://www.drush.org/) and mess with your web site.

Comment: So you're saying it is within the realms of possibility changes can be made without leaving a trace in the server logs?

Comment: Absolutely. Using drush might leave something in Drupal logs if you've enabled them, but performing the same actions manually, or from malware, will leave no logs anywhere.

Comment: If you would like to add your comment as an answer, I will check it as “accepted” - thanks.